# Why is valid xpath in chrome developer console not recognized by selenium / python / chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python 3.6.5 64bit and the latest version of Selenium Webdriver and Google chromedriver.  My IDE is Visual Studio Code.

I have been able to locate and use every element I have needed of hundreds over multiple web automation projects. I often use the Chrome developer console to identify and test for valid Xpath selectors.

Now I have an element that was identified and tested using Chrome developer console, but it does not work in my python script.

Given an HTML structure of:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
   <form name='someform'>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>
                  <font>...</font>
                  <br>
                  "
                  This is the text I am searching for."
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Content I am using
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Content I am using
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome developer consoles gives an Xpath of:
    "/html/body/form/table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YkqK.jpg)/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YkqK.jpg)/th"
and correctly identifies the element and can display all node data.
[image]

Also tested various versions of
    contains(text(),'text I am')
which of course all work as expected, along with two or three other valid Xpath selectors.

The script has already made hundreds of selenium calls when I come to this in my code:

```
try:
   tableHeader = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th")
   #grab tableHeader text and do something with it...
except:
   print("Selenium Error:", sys.exc()[0])
```

And all of these valid Xpaths fail:

```
Selenium Error: <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>
```

The page in question is much longer than the example above, but continues in the same simple structure. There are no iframes.

I cannot find any reason for this and am further frustrated by the fact that another part of the same script works with a different page on the same website that has the EXACT same structure and I can reference the exact same element on that page with the exact same Xpath selector with no issue.

The only thing I can think of is that the element contains a carriage return / newline before the text, as you can see above.  I don't see how this would affect identifying the element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried finding a list of  elements on the active page and seeing if any of those contain the element you are looking for?

```
tableHeaders = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')
```

You should be able to navigate through tableHeaders and find the  element where the Text value matches what you desire.

Comment: It turns out I had no issue besides a muddy brain. Thank you for your response. Going back to my IDE to test your code above, I was gobsmacked to realize I was working on the wrong block of code.

Comment: How would I go about getting a list of active elements on the page?

Comment: @Trialsman Glad to be of assistance. As far as list of active elements, I would suggest using the same line of code above and seeing what elements in that list are "Displayed" and "Enabled", deeming them active. What that looks in like Python code, I'm not exactly sure since C# is my native code

Answer (score 0):

Good grief! I have tunnel vision... been staring at this screen for too long today.  There were two calls, a hundred lines apart. I was trying the variations on the second call when in fact it was the first call above that was throwing the exception. It was there in front of me as obvious as the screens glaring back at me. I just wasted two hours on this.

My Xpath works perfectly well, as expected. As so often is the case, I was the problem.